# emacs ruby-mode key bindings not working (mac osx)

Tags: ruby, emacs, elisp

I am using Emacs 23.4.1 on my MacBook as a ruby development environment when I am on the go. Although `ruby-mode` works, Emacs doesn't appear to recognize ruby specific key bindings. For example, invoking `C-c C-r` isn't recognized, but manually invoking the command `ruby-send-region` via `M-x` will work.

I should note that on my Linux VM using Emacs 23.4.1, the above key binding works, and when I manually invoke the command with `M-x` Emacs will remind me in the minibuffer that I can instead use the aforementioned key binding. In the case of my OS X machine, do I manually need to define the key bindings in my ruby configuration file? If so, is there someone be kind enough to give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: I don't know, but have you tried <kbd>Command<kbd/> instead of <kbd>Control<kbd/>?

Comment: `Ctrl` is still used in the OSX version of Emacs. I am using both the Cocoa and command-line versions.

Comment: Have you checked to see if on your mac install there is a conflicting command for that key?

Comment: @diedthreetimes: as far as I know, there isn't a conflicting command `C-c C-r`, because Emacs doesn't recognize the command. Or were you asking if the command is used by the operating system? If that is the case, I don't think the above key binding would be used by the Mac/Cocoa API, since Mac API commands use the apple key and not `Ctrl` ... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ruby-send-region` comes from inf-ruby.  Which version are you running?  There
are various bastardized versions that load its keys automatically, which is
what may be happening on Linux.

The [canonical version](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/misc/inf-ruby.el) of this comes from Ruby source.  It does not load
keys automatically.  However, the loading instructions it does provide are
suboptimal, since key-binding code is run every time `ruby-mode` is activated.
Instead use this:

```
(autoload 'run-ruby "inf-ruby"
"Run an inferior Ruby process")
(autoload 'inf-ruby-keys "inf-ruby" 
"Set local key defs for inf-ruby in ruby-mode")
(eval-after-load "ruby-mode" '(inf-ruby-keys))
```

Comment: Oh, and to answer the first part of your question: my version of ruby-mode seems to be the latest one via the subversion repository.